# Obtaining topic description in search api

Tags: freebase

I seem to be having problem pulling out the text content of the following query without making another call:

http://tinyurl.com/mgsewz2 via the `mqlread` api

```
{
  "id": "/en/alcatraz_island",
  "/common/topic/description": [{}],
  "/common/topic/topic_equivalent_webpage": [],
  "/common/topic/official_website": null
}
```

I can't retrieve the following

1. description
2. equivalent webpage (I'm looking for the en wiki page)
   , but I can obtain the `official_website` url.

It looks like I can get it via the `search` api via `output=` but I can't walk through the entire set that I'm looking for without getting `search request is too large` error.
http://markmail.org/message/hd6pcveta7bhuz25#query:+page:1+mid:u7xegxlhtmhwiqbl+state:results

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It you want to download large subsets of Freebase data, your best bet is to use the [Freebase RDF Dumps](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data). They contain all the properties that you listed above.